# EF core code first, loose foreign key contraint after making it nullable

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.1

I had this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    //some more properties
}

public class Payment
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int CustomerId {get; set;} //foreign key
    public Customer Customer {get; set;}
}
```

Which lead to a foreign key constraint in the database. Then I made the CustomerId nullable:

```
public class Payment
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int? CustomerId {get; set;} //foreign key
    public Customer Customer {get; set;}
}
```

If I generate the migration script, I get something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'MyMigration')
BEGIN

DECLARE @var2 sysname;

    SELECT @var2 = [d].[name]
      FROM [sys].[default_constraints] [d]
INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] [c] ON [d].[parent_column_id] = [c].[column_id] 
       AND [d].[parent_object_id] = [c].[object_id]
     WHERE ([d].[parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[Payments]') AND [c].[name] = N'CustomerId');

IF @var2 IS NOT NULL EXEC(N'ALTER TABLE [Payments] 
    DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var2 + '];');

ALTER TABLE [Payments] ALTER COLUMN [CustomerId] int NULL;
END;

GO
```

So now column Payments.CustomerId is nullable, but the foreign key constraint is removed. How can I get the foreign key constraint back?

edit: One more thing. Between my code changes, I also added this in protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder):

```
new PaymentMap(modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>());
```

Comment: Have you tried to add 
Public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments {get;set;} inside Customer class?

Comment: The script looks incomplete. My test continues with `ALTER TABLE [Payments] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Payments_Customers_CustomerId] FOREIGN KEY ([CustomerId]) REFERENCES [Customers] ([Id]) ON DELETE NO ACTION;` and then inserting migration history record.

Comment: The script is incomplete, but mine lacks the part with "ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Payments_Customers_CustomerId] FOREIGN KEY...". That's exactly why I asked my question here

Comment: I've tested with EF Core 2.1.4 / SqlServer, what is your environment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate it with `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKeyAttribute` explicitly:

```
public class Payment
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public int? CustomerId {get; set;} //foreign key

    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public Customer Customer {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: There is no need to add ForeignKeyAttribute, if naming conventions are fine.
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/conventions-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: It worked without [ForeignKey("CustomerId")] before, in the old situation.

Comment: @Richard, as far as I know, naming conventions works when **type** of foreign key property is matching **type** of primary key of relative class. And it works like a charm before. But now, `int?` (nullable int) type of `Payment.CustomerId` doesn't match `int` type of `Customer.Id` so EF need your hint about this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work you should add `public virtual ICollection<Tenant> Payments { get; set;}` to `Customer` class

Blockquote

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}

public class Payment
{
    public int PaymentId{ get; set; }
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do the trick. I still miss my foreign key constraint.

Comment: `virtual ICollection<T>` stuff are primary is for lazy loading

Answer (score 0):

As EF Core requires manually making the connections between tables, have you tried to write them down in your DataContext class?

Add `List<Payment> Payments` in your `Customer` class and in your DataContext class in the `OnModelCreate` override method add:

```
builder
     .Entity<Payment>()
     .HasOne(p => p.Customer)
     .WithMany(c => c.Payments)
     .HasForeignKey(p => p.CustomerId);
```

Comment: _"EF Core requires manually making the connections between tables"_ - this is not true. Most of the time there is an [applicable convention](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/conventions-in-ef-core.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I dropped my local database and re-created it with "update-database". That solved my problem. Thanks everybody for their time and effort!